# ended event not firing in a playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, event-listener, playlist

I've been following and personalizing [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtZCMTtP-0Y&ab_channel=Nels-WebDeveloper%28MicroTechTutorials%29) to create a playlist.
My problem is that when an audio ends, the event listener does not detect it, so the following audio is not automatically played.
I think this may be because my audios are played on clic (with "onclick" in the html), and not loaded in the player.

Here is the html :

```
<body>
   
         <audio controls id="audioPlayer" autoplay="false">
         Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
         </audio>
      

<ul id="playlist">
         <li class="current-song" >
         <a class="audio song" 
         src="test.wav"
         onclick="playAudio('test.wav')">
         test
         </a></li>

         <li><a class="audio song" src="algebrasuicide_fathersbythedoor.wav" onclick=
          "playAudio('algebrasuicide_fathersbythedoor.wav')">algebra suicide <i>father by the door</i> 
         </a></li>
      
         <li><a class="audio song" src="algebrasuicide_inbedwithboys.wav" onclick=
         "playAudio('algebrasuicide_inbedwithboys.wav')">
         algebra suicide <i>in bed with boys</i> 
       </a></li>
         

         <li><a class="audio song"
            src="aprilmagazine_parade.wav"
            onclick="playAudio('aprilmagazine_parade.wav')">
         april magazine <i>parade</i>
         </a></li>
   <ul>

         <button id="button">PAUSE</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
        // loads the audio player
        audioPlayer();
    </script>
 </body>
```

and here is the js :

```
let audio;

function stopAudio() {
  // If audio in not undefined and if is playing, pause it
  if (audio && !audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind track to beginning (is you need this)
  }
}

function playAudio(src) {
  stopAudio();             // Pause any currently playing
  audio = new Audio();      // Save a reference
  audio.src = src;
  audio.play();
}

function pauseAudio(){
    audio.pause();
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    button.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    pauseAudio();
    button.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
});

 
function audioPlayer(){
          var currentSong = 0;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
            $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault(); 
               $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
               $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
            });
          }
            
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
              alert("hi");
              currentSong++;
                if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                    currentSong = 0;
                $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
              }); 
$(document).ready(function() {
   audioPlayer();
});
```

If someone knows how I could do to automatically play the next audio of the list I'm very interested, I'd love to understand where is the error of logic in this code :)
I'm very new to coding so maybe the answer to this in simple.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that you were using two Audio elements. One in the DOM in your `<audio>` element, the other in-memory in the `audio` variable.  As such, you weren't hooking the `ended` event handler to the Audio which was actually playing.

I've fixed this in the example below by only using the in-memory version of Audio. I've also tidied some of your other logic as there were parts which were unnecessary, and other which can be improved.

For example, don't use inline `onclick` attributes. Add your event handlers unobtrusively in JS. If you need to pass data to functions, place the argument in a `data` attribute in the HTML and read it from the DOM when the event fires.

Also note that it's better to stick to one library, so I removed jQuery, as you only used it in a couple of places, and replaced that logic with plain JS instead.

Here's a working example. You can see the file changes after the first file, which is around 45 seconds, ends. Unfortunately the first file was the shortest one which I could find which was freely available for the demo!

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
const li = document.querySelectorAll('#playlist li');
let audio = new Audio();
audio.volume = 0.15; // so we don't deafen people for this demo

const stopAudio = () => {
  if (!audio.paused) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
}

const playAudio = src => {
  stopAudio();
  audio.src = src;
  audio.play();
}

const togglePause = () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    button.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    button.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", togglePause);

// add the click event handler to the li elements so they play audio when clicked.
document.querySelectorAll('#playlist li a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    li.forEach(li => li.classList.remove("current-song"));

    const a = e.currentTarget;
    playAudio(a.dataset.fileurl);
    a.closest('li').classList.add("current-song");
  });
});

// move to the next file when one ends
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  const playingLi = document.querySelector('li.current-song');
  playingLi.classList.remove('current-song');
  
  const nextLi = playingLi.nextElementSibling;
  nextLi.classList.add('current-song');
  playAudio(nextLi.querySelector('a').dataset.fileurl);
});
```

```css
.current-song { 
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
  <li>
    <a class="audio song" src="algebrasuicide_fathersbythedoor.wav" data-fileurl="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3">
      algebra suicide <i>father by the door</i> 
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="audio song" src="algebrasuicide_inbedwithboys.wav" data-fileurl="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/audio/TalkNerdyToMe.mp3">
      algebra suicide <i>in bed with boys</i> 
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="button">Pause</button>
```

Comment: This works very well ! Thank you very much ! Your explanations and advices help me a lot to improve, now I understand the errors I made. I accepted your answer, is there anything more I can do to show gratitude ? :)

Comment: Glad to help - accepting the answer is gratitude enough :)